# Webpack fails to load bootstrap v4.0.0-beta

Tags: javascript, webpack, bootstrap-4

I've recently made a config with webpack and bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 which worked fine until today when I tried to change to v4 beta and now I can't seem to make it work properly :(
I have this config:

> webpack.config.js

```
entry: {
    app: "./src/app.js"
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node-modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
        {   test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }),
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }           
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ // inject ES5 modules as global vars
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('/css/[name].css'),
```

in my *app.js* I have the `require('bootstrap');`
Now when I try to make  build now I get an error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-es2015-modules-strip" specified in "E:\\Documente\\Work\\wordpress\\wordpressSite\\wp-content\\themes\\bsTheme\\node_modules\\bootstra
p\\.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "E:\\Documente\\Work\\wordpress\\wordpressSite\\wp-content\\themes\\bsTheme\\node_modules\\bootstrap"
```

The issue seems to be here in `bootstrap/.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "es2015",
            {
                "loose": true,
                "modules": false
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-strip"
    ]
}
```

I tried to go in bootstrap directory and ran: `npm install` (i don't know why I should do that since I already have my own config for bable/autoprefixer)
 I already have babel-core, babel-loader, babel-preset-es2015 installed in my own package.json I installed `transform-es2015-modules-strip` and ran build again:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'E:\Documente\Work\wordpress\wordpressSite\wp-content\themes\bsTheme\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'
 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 1:0-17
 @ ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in 'E:\Documente\Work\wordpress\wordpressSite\wp-content\themes\bsTheme\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'
 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 1:0-20
 @ ./src/app.js
```

So I tried and installed jquery and popper in my project as dev dependency...got rid of the jquery error but..:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in 'E:\Documente\Work\wordpress\wordpressSite\wp-content\themes\bsTheme\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'
 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 1:0-20
 @ ./src/app.js
```

Out of ideas...and this seems over complicated...I can't seem to know what I'm doing wrong, the only thing I can come up with is to get the `bootstrap.js` file put it directly with my other js files... long post but I wanted to be as specific as possible.

What should I do to make it work again, I would really appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: Don't npm install from another modules source directory, firstly try to rm -rf node_modules.  Then reinstall them and see what happens

Comment: Tried that again (already did that 2 times already) this time i had popper and  jquery in my dev dependencies  but I still got that same last error:
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in...

Comment: and what happens if you remove Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'] from your webpack?

Comment: It did the build without errors when I removed popper from webpack.config.js, thank you. 
I got the config from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/   I'm still confused about the whole webpack bootstrat config, still not sure of if I still need to install Jquery as a dependency or if  i still need other configs, I will test some more and see.

Comment: you do need jquery to use the mobile responsive menu button on the navbar

Comment: include bootstrap as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined

Answer (score 60, accepted):

After several tests this is my conclusion for running `bootstrap v4.0.0-beta` with `Webpack` so you will need to manually install jquery and popper.js, it will not be installed by bootstrap as dependencies anymore. It will not work without jquery and the dropdowns/popups will not work without popper.js so:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta -D
npm install jquery -D
npm install popper.js -D
```

I ended up editing the post, because it was pointed out that popper and popper.js are 2 different libraries(which I didn't knew) I was trying to install popper.js with `npm install popper` and therefore I had the issue... so installing it with `npm install popper.js` will install the latest version of it (and the right library).
Then you have to change in the webpack.config.js just as mentioned in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/

```
plugins: [
    ...
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],            
        ...
      })
    ...
  ]
```

Then the rest of the config should be the same as it was for v4 alpha. Anyway this is what I found out after struggling with this for a while. Hope it will help someone.

Comment: Installing `popper.js` you'll get `popper.js@1.12.0`, `popper` is a completely different library that has nothing do to with `popper.js`

Comment: Now BS recommend using popper.js@1.12.3 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23626

Comment: Does this works for Webpack 1 as well ?? 

Still I am using webpack 1 :( and getting some nasty error saying 
 
  `this.state.current.addBlock is not a function`

Is there is any solution for this?

Comment: @Alin Faur, Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I get the same result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539120/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-jquery-when-when-importing-bootstrap?noredirect=1#comment92018935_52539120

Answer (score 11):

I got this error when upgraded to `bootstarp` latest version `4.0.0`.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in 'E:\work\nodejs\mepos\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'
 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 7:100-120
```

I just added `popper.js` dependency and it resolved the issue. *(`jquery` was already added in my dependencies)*

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I found same error
and after some search find design find solution:

First of all you need install:

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-strip
```

And them install:

```
babel-preset-es2015
babel-preset-stage-2
```

Also i attached to image before and after.
Hope is help.

Comment: hi there can you explain your above answer: why are you installing the babel plugin?

Answer (score -1):

It's because of popper, I think? Popper v1.10 isn't available over npm, so you probably installed Popper v1.0.0 instead.

Comment: @temuz Popper.js@1.10.0 is available on npm, it has been released the 2017-06-14T16:20:28.282Z according to the npm logs.

Answer (score -1):

install the bootstrap without the signal: ^ (npm install bootstrap@^4.0.0-alpha.6)

like this: npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6