# Bootstrap 4: Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I've installed Bootstrap 4 using Node and Gulp and when running the application I get the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined

I've only been using the Bootstrap grid system so far and I haven't used anything that would require the Bootstrap JS. Looks to me like Bootstrap is missing something or I haven't installed it correctly (to be honest it's probably me) - has anyone else come across the same issue or know a fix at all?

Comment: That works - thanks! If you want to pop that in as the answer for future readers I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: You may wish to revisit this question and change the accepted answer to [the one written by a Bootstrap maintainer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46971076/114900), rather than the currently-accepted one.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Since our Bootstrap beta 2 release, we added two new dist files : `bootstrap.bundle.js` and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` which contain `Popper.js` inside

Plus use this link to find the latest release of Popper.js : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/popper.js because the above linked release (1.8.2) is very old, latest is 1.12.9

BTW you should choose the UMD release of Popper.js because it's the one used by Bootstrap

Comment: nice! maybe also get rid of the npm warning `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Comment: Yep we removed that warning in our latest beta2 too :)

Comment: This message is still there. Here's a fragment of the console output from my Yarn install::

`[3/4]  Linking dependencies...
warning "bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.12.3".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 43.43s.`

Comment: Strange :-/ please do not hesitate to open an issue in our Github

Comment: @Johann-S I hope this isn't a dumb question, but does that mean bootstrap.bundle.min.js replaces bootstrap.min.js? I'm assuming yes...

Comment: @Sal_Vader_808 yep exactly !
bootstrap.bundle.min.js contains Bootstrap + Popper.js

Answer (score 25):

Use **bootstrap.bundle.js** that already has **popper.js** NPM path **'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'**.

Comment: It solves an issue for me and has not got any dependency error as such.

Answer (score 22):

For those struggling with this issue on Webpack: In your entry file,
**import 'bootstrap'** does give the error. You need to remove that and replace it with **import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'**

This is sufficient and you don't need to import Popper separately. That applies for bootstrap 4.0.0.beta2

Answer (score 15):

In my case it turned out that the **popper.js** script should be called before **bootstrap.js**.

```
<script src="https://../popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://../bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Changing the order in my rails 5 application.js worked too, thanks!

Comment: excellent, fixed my issue :) not all of us are offered the opportunity to change bootstrap, so this worked a charm!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and have been playing around with it for half a day over a simple carousel.  Safari on Mac didn't give feedback properly in that there is a priority on libraries:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Reviewing the error I ran across "You need JQ before BS for this to work", so I tried it, also putting `Popper` before BS.

So I have all of these in my `<head>` and boom it worked.

Answer (score 1):

1-Copy code on this page: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js

2-Past on new file and save on this name (popper.min.js)

3-Add script on html before bootstrap script:

```
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same. I'm on Rails and i followed bootstrap 4 gem installation from  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem. I just make popper requirement in application.js first, like this :

```
//= require popper
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are here and trying to add popper v2 to Laravel

1. <strike>in package.json at devDependencies section we have
   `"popper.js": "^1.12"`,
   so remove this string</strike>. As official doc says they move to `@popperjs` scope name. If you have any v1 poppers used in project follow the migrate guide v1 to v2 from doc. **UPD**: this sht is required by bootstrap. so, i had to reinstall it after remove. skip this step.
2. in console `npm i @popperjs/core`
3. in bootstrap.js at try section add
   `window.Popper = require('@popperjs/core')`
4. rebuild your js in console `npm run dev`
5. ok, now you can make your instance
   `let _instance = Popper.createPopper(element, tooltip, {})`