# Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined - with Bootstrap 4 and Webpack 3.8.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using the Visual Studio 2017 Angular template with .NET Core 2.0. The template has numerous older dependencies which I have updated, including to Angular 5.0.0. Running the vanilla template with Bootstrap 3.x.x works. However, using **Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2** results in the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined

I have followed the instructions here to the best of my ability:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/

I have looked at this issue:

[Bootstrap 4: Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined)

Per the solutions listed there, I have to to either register popper before bootstrap or to use the min version of boostrap since it comes with popper already. However, I am using webpack 2.5.1 (which I am just now learning) and I don't know how to implement either of those solutions in the **webpack.config.js** file which was provided as part of the template and includes the modification called out by the boostrap-webpack docs.

***webpack.config.js***

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
                // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
                //Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
                //Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown"
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new AotPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module.browser#AppModule'),
                    exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
                })
            ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module.server#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
            })
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

Also, here is the main entry point file **boot.browser.ts** provided as part of the template:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module.browser';

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => {
        // Before restarting the app, we create a new root element and dispose the old one
        const oldRootElem = document.querySelector('app');
        const newRootElem = document.createElement('app');
        oldRootElem!.parentNode!.insertBefore(newRootElem, oldRootElem);
        modulePromise.then(appModule => appModule.destroy());
    });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}

// Note: @ng-tools/webpack looks for the following expression when performing production
// builds. Don't change how this line looks, otherwise you may break tree-shaking.
const modulePromise = platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how to get past the error. I used the following lines in the main entry point **boot.browser.ts** file:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

//These two lines didn't remove the error
//import Popper from 'popper.js';
//import 'bootstrap';

//This one did remove the error. The bundle version of bootstrap includes popper in the correct order (according to the docs)
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js';
```

Interestingly, the suggested code at the bootstrap github (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24648) was to use this line for the jquery import:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

instead of

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

but the former caused this error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'jquery'

However, I have no idea what the difference is between the two lines

Answer (score 1):

try to include Popper.js before bootstrap not after

```
 "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
 "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

Comment: Yes but how do I do that given that the webpack.config.js basically just crawls through the js files and bundles them? How do I tell webpack the inclusion order given the specific libraries aren't even listed? I've started looking at webpack (I'm totally new to it) but haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: where are you including bootstrap.js, are you using angular cli?

Comment: try to use the umd distribution      'Popper': 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper' instead of  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],

Comment: @ Fateh Mohamed - As I understand it, bootstrap is included as part of the entry point file boot.browser.ts and popper is handled by webpack.config.js in the line popper: ['popper.js', 'default']. But like I said, I am unfamiliar with webpack so I don't know how to force it to either make popper go in first or to use the umd version. I tried replacing the popper: line in the webpack config as you suggestted with Popper: 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper' but that didn't help

Comment: And no, I'm not using angular cli directly. I haven't even created any components yet. I'm just using the vanilla template files and am attempting to upgrade it to bootstrap 4 (while still using webpack)

Answer (score 1):

I installed a particular version of popper.js I knew was working with bootstrap 4.0.0-beta like so:

```
npm install popper.js@1.12.5 --save-dev
```

Then I only had to add it to my webpack.config.vendor.js like so:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin(
            { 
                $: 'jquery', 
                jQuery: 'jquery', // }, Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
                jquery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                Popper: 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js'                     
            }                
        ),
```

and I no longer received the *Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined* error.

I made no code changes, only webpack and npm changes.