# Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined

Tags: reactjs, popper.js

I just started working on a project that was developed by another developer (reactjs project) , however when I try to start the project I get this error in the browser console :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined
```

The error is pointing to a specific line of course which is in the file :

```
node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
```

the error in the last line of the following :

```
    var bootstrap = (function (exports,$,Popper) {
'use strict';

$ = $ && $.hasOwnProperty('default') ? $['default'] : $;
Popper = Popper && Popper.hasOwnProperty('default') ? Popper['default'] : Popper;

 // a lot of generated code 


}({},$,Popper));
```

As I said earlier the error shows up pointing to the last line with the error mentioned before

Note : I have searched all other possible answers here in stack overflow but with no luck , including this answer [Bootstrap 4: Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined) so please it is not a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4: Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined)

Comment: @AndyRay not a duplicate I've already checked that answer he used another way to implement popper and bootstrap , didn't work for me

Comment: You can follow this[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined/47089920#47089920](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined/47089920#47089920)

Comment: You can follow [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined/47089920#47089920](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined/47089920#47089920)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the code , the problem was that I had an old version of nodejs and npm on my machine I thought this might help someone in the future.