# When navbar button is clicked the menu is not appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this html below relative to a navbar using bootstrap. The issue is that when the button to open the navbar is clicked the navbar dont appears. The jquery and bootstrap jquery files are being imported.

Do you know where is the issue?

working example (http://jsfiddle.net/7fhs23bt/)

html:

```
<div class="container px-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex align-items-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: It's that popper is not defined thing again with Bootstrap and JQuery. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running your code - and using the Inspector of Chrome - it said "popper" is not defined.

A quick Google says that you need to include popper library - however this is already included if you use the Bundle from Bootstrap.

Replace your current CDN reference to Bootstrap with https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

That will resolve your issue - here's a working snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container px-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex align-items-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need any clarification on how I troubleshooted this