# NPM WARN: bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of popper.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4

I have follow dependency part in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "*",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "bower": "^1.8.2",
    "chosen-js": "^1.8.2",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "jQuery-QueryBuilder": "^2.4.5",
    "jquery": "^1.4",
    "jquery-tagit": "*",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "prismjs": "^1.8.1",
    "qtip2": "^3.0.3",
    "multi-step-modal": 
        "git+ssh://git@git.ias.su:2022/dependencies/multi-step-modal.git"
}
```

When I run `npm update`, I get:

```
LPS@1.0.0 /home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/lps/public
├── bootstrap@4.0.0 
├── jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.0 
├── multi-step-modal@1.0.0  (git+ssh://git@git.ias.su:2022/dependencies/multi-step-modal.git#2f9bc29093c9939c2ba23fa18fd22001a74040d2)
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY popper.js@^1.12.9
└── prismjs@1.12.2 

npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.9 but none was installed.
```

I searched for the reason and found just this: [Bootstrap 4: Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined)

I know that it is just warning, but I always keep my code warning-free.

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap 4 requires popper. Add `"popper.js": "^1.12.9"` to the package.json

Comment: Thanx. Also it is important to include files from umd folder, since it called from browser directly.

Comment: Put your answer in answers, I will mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**[Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) is not really necessary**

Bootstrap 4.0.0 release contains 2 new files `bootstrap.bundle.js` and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` which contain Popper.js inside and you really do not need it.

**`bootstrap.bundle.min.js` is exactly Bootstrap.js + Popper.js.**

*In [Bootstrap v4.0.0 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) it is still mentioned that you need the file for some components*

[Components requiring JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

- Dropdowns for displaying and positioning (also requires [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/))
- Tooltips and popovers for displaying and positioning (also requires [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/))

*I have not tested it but I think it is not necessary*

**Solutions**

You can use the NPM path 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'.

Or if you finally want to download `Popper.js`, download the version you need.

***bootstrap/package.json***

- [Bootstrap v4.0.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0/package.json#L208) `"popper.js": "^1.12.9"`
- [Bootstrap v4.1.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.1/package.json#L215) `"popper.js": "^1.14.1"`

Comment: how to "use the NPM path 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'." ?

Comment: In my case, looking upper in my logs, the missing part was to set a PYTHON env var ...

Answer (score 12):

**Bootstrap 4.0.0** requires popper, so just add `"popper.js": "^1.12.9"` to the package.json

For example **dropdown**, **tooltips** and **popovers** won't work:
[image]

https://www.codeply.com/go/CuOfa7UnUA (broken w/o popper)

Note: As of **4.1**, popper.js is only *required* for dropdowns, tooltips and popovers.

Comment: Can you please make an example where something is not working without the popper.js?

Answer (score 5):

If it is saying as follows image in, then

[image]

It is asking for install popper.js for your project. So get the cmd on your project location and run the following command.

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

Then you can see as in following image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have to add `"popper.js":"^require_version"` into package.json under the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue for **Bootstrap with Angular**,  while I was installing Bootstrap not in the directory where the Angular project was created.
It worked successfully in my case every time I installed it in the angular directory/folder look at when installed in the project folder.

[image: install bootstrap in project folder]