# Rails - Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, popper.js

Having  problems with the update of bootstrap & popper.
Ive tried every thing and keep getting error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined.

My images will not show. I followed a couple of suggestions from [Bootstrap 4: Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined). but still no images.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined

I had a similar issue when I tried integrating *Bootstrap 4* into my *Rails 5* app and none of posts that I found couldn't able to fix my problem. This is how I fixed the error.

**Step #1**

Copied the `popper.min` source code to a file(namely `popper.min.js`) and placed that file under `app/assets/javascripts`

**Step #2**

And finally added `//= require popper.min` to `application.js`

Hope this resolve your problem.

Comment: can you send a link for popper.min source code. I followed all ur steps except info for file popper.min.js

Comment: @AgeliqueB Here it is https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js

Comment: @AgeliqueB Did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: so it turned out to be - I had to change back  false to true - config.assets.compile = true

Comment: a warning came up in my terminal saying to change to false, so i did & didnt think twice about it. the little things that you dont think about.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the order in which you are requiring the cdns is correct? double check that. Without knowing what your code looks like, it sounds like either your CDN is no good or you are not loading the scripts in the right order hence the error.

Check for any typing errors in/around where you are requiring the cdns.

Next make sure that have it required in the application.js

give that a good comb through first, those are the usual suspects