# I want to create multiple (i.e approx 4) On/Off toggle button

Tags: python

I am new to Flask and want to create multiple(approx 4 buttons) On/Off toggle button on my website. I was wondering if and how this is possible also including a dynamic label.

index.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="checkbox"  class='toggle' checked data-toggle="toggle">
    <div class='status'>Toggled</div>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="toggle1" checked data-toggle="toggle1">
    <div class="status1">Toggled2</div>
  </body>

  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
     var current_status = $('.status').text();
     $.ajax({
      url: "/get_toggled_status",
      type: "get",
      data: {status: current_status},
      success: function(response) {
        $(".status").html(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {

      }
    });
   });



  });

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.toggle1').click(function() {
      var current_status1 = $('.status1').text();
      $.ajax({
       url: "/get_toggled_status1",
       type: "get",
       data: {status: current_status1},
       success: function(response) {
         $(".status1").html(response);
       },
       error: function(xhr) {

       }
     });
    });
   });
 </script>


 </html>
```

app.py(for routes)

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, redirect, url_for


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/switch_led', methods=['POST'])
def move_forward():
    if request.form['demo1']=='ON':
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'ID':'APPLIANCE1',
                'sequence':1
                }
            )
        ar="PRESS TO UPDATE"
        templateData ={
        'ar':ar
        }
    if request.form['demo1']=='OFF':
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'ID':'APPLIANCE1',
                'sequence':0
                }
            )
        ar="CHECK DATABASE"
        templateData ={
        'ar':ar
        }
    if request.form['demo2']=='ON':
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'ID':'APPLIANCE2',
                'sequence':1
                }
            )
        ar="PRESS TO UPDATE"
        templateData ={
        'ar':ar
        }
    if request.form['demo2']=='OFF':
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'ID':'APPLIANCE2',
                'sequence':0
                }
            )
        ar="CHECK DATABASE"
        templateData ={
        'ar':ar
        }
    if request.form['demo3']=='ON':
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'ID':'APPLIANCE3',
                'sequence':1
                }
            )
        ar="PRESS TO UPDATE"
        templateData ={
        'ar':ar
        }
    if request.form['demo3']=='OFF':
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'ID':'APPLIANCE3',
                'sequence':0
                }
            )
        ar="CHECK DATABASE"
        templateData ={
        'ar':ar
        }
    if request.form['demo4']=='ON':
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'ID':'LOCK',
                'sequence':1
                }
            )
        ar="PRESS TO UPDATE"
        templateData ={
        'ar':ar
        }
    if request.form['demo4']=='OFF':
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'ID':'LOCK',
                'sequence':0
                }
            )
        ar="CHECK DATABASE"
        templateData ={
        'ar':ar
        }



    return render_template('index.html', **templateData);

@app.route('/get_toggled_status') 
def get_toggled_status():
  current_status = request.args.get('status')
  return 'Toggled' if current_status == 'Untoggled' else 'Untoggled'

@app.route('/get_toggled_status1') 
def get_toggled_status1():
  current_status1 = request.args.get('status1')
  return 'Toggled' if current_status1 == 'Untoggled' else 'Untoggled'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug='true')
```

My result is that it shows 2 toggle button named toggle and toggle1. But on clicking the button named toggle...it shows output as a toggle when ON and untoggle when OFF. Up to this point, everything gor=es fine. But when I click on 2nd button named toggled1, it performs the action on 1st toggle button not on the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your html code like below:

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox"  class='toggle' checked
    data-toggle="toggle" onclick="change_status('.status')">
    <div class='status'>Toggled</div>

    <input type="checkbox"  class="toggle1" checked
    data-toggle="toggle1" onclick="change_status('.status2')">
    <div class="status1">Toggled2</div>
  </body>
```

The js code will be similar to this:

```
function change_status(status_class) {
     var current_status = $(status_class).text();
     $.ajax({
      url: "/get_toggled_status",
      type: "get",
      data: {status: current_status},
      success: function(response) {
        $(status_class).html(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {

      }
    });
   }
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() 
   {
   function change_status(status) {
     var current_status = $('.status').text();
     $.ajax({
      url: "/get_toggled_status",
      type: "get",
      data: {status: current_status},
      success: function(response) {
        $('.status').html(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
      }
    });
   };
  };                                                  This is what i wrote..but code is not working..may be i wrote  something wrote..hope you can tell me..please.   And thank you very much for the previous answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad. The function should be out of $(document).ready(). I edit my answer.

Comment: Sir, i have already added this function, but it still not working. It shows "Undefined error: popper is not defined"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24984

Comment: Anytime, glad it helped.